# mysqli prepare и union

Tags: mysqli, preparedstatement

Есть 2 вапроса, не знаю как использовать union в mysqli prepared statement

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare('SELECT `d`.`id`,`d`.`uniqid`,`d`.`title`,`d`.`read`,`u`.`user`,
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE `module`="dialog" AND `modID` = `d`.`id`) as comms
                FROM `dialogs` `d`
                LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON (`d`.`sender` = `u`.`id`)                              
                WHERE `d`.`recipient` = ? 
                GROUP by `d`.`id`');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $myid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$uniqid,$title,$read,$sender,$comments);
$stmt->store_result();
```

вот второй вопрос тоже похож

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare('SELECT `d`.`id`,`d`.`uniqid`,`d`.`title`,`d`.`read`,`u`.`user`,
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE `module`="dialog" AND `modID` = `d`.`id`) as comms
                FROM `dialogs` `d`
                LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON (`d`.`recipient` = `u`.`id`)                               
                WHERE `d`.`sender` = ? 
                GROUP by `d`.`id`');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $myid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$uniqid,$title,$read,$sender,$comments);
$stmt->store_result();
```

меняется только

```
ON (`d`.`recipient` = `u`.`id`)                             
WHERE `d`.`sender` = ?
```

или может есть идей как лучше оргонизововать модуль лючных сообщений в виде диалогов...

Comment: `ON u.id=IF(d.sender=?,d.recipient,d.sender) WHERE d.sender=? or d.recipient=?` и `bind_param('iii', $myid, $myid, $myid)`

Comment: тогда придется добавить еше один жойн LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON (`d`.`recipient` = `u`.`id`)

Comment: Зачем ? Вы же имя только второго пользователя получаете, который НЕ тот что передан параметром. `IF()` в join именно это и сделает выберет ID либо реципиента либо сендара в зависимости от того кто из них НЕ переданный (IF это функция MySQL, можете конечно вместо нее case написать, но он громоздкий)

Comment: помогло, спасибо